# Set Screen Lock Setting in "None"

Tags: android

I need to set Screen Lock Setting to "None" in the android system.
I am deploying an app that is being sent out to users on pre-configured tablets.
This pre-configuration is done manually by the tablet supplier.
The settings to pre-configure is to set the Screen lock to None when the app is installing.

Comment: do you think in power WakeLock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, the user has to do it them self.

Considering all apps (With a similar requirment) I have used  so far send me to the "Select lock screen" screen & ask me to disable it manually.

I could be wrong tho!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    try{
        Class lockPatternUtilsCls = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils");
        Constructor lockPatternUtilsConstructor =
                lockPatternUtilsCls.getConstructor(new Class[]{Context.class});
        Object lockPatternUtils = lockPatternUtilsConstructor.newInstance(getContext());

        Method setLockScreenDisabled = lockPatternUtils.getClass().getMethod("setLockScreenDisabled", boolean.class ,int.class);
        setLockScreenDisabled.invoke(lockPatternUtils, new Object[]{true,0});
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(this.toString(),e.toString());
    }
```

if you want change lock to swipe:

```
 setLockScreenDisabled.invoke(lockPatternUtils, new Object[]{false,0});
```

but you need to change your app to system uid:

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```